# If Statement Providing Wrong Output

Tags: java, if-statement, netbeans

I coded a banking program. I'm at the point where the user must enter their pin, and it must be compared to their pin which is taken from a text file. The problem is, I have an if statement, and the condition is met, but it keeps giving me an the statement as if it was not met.

I've tried switch statements and even using a boolean value, but it does not work

```
    public String getPin(){
     return pin;
    }

    String pin2 = lbl_Pin.getText();
    System.out.println(pin2);
    System.out.println(getPin());

    // Allows the user to select what they want to do after they enter the
    // correct pin
    if (pin2.equals(String.valueOf(getPin()))) {
        btn_SelectLoan.setEnabled(true);
        btn_SelectWithdraw.setEnabled(true);
        btn_SelectDeposit.setEnabled(true);
        btn_Balance.setEnabled(true);
        lbl_Loan.setVisible(true);
        lbl_Withdraw.setVisible(true);
        lbl_Deposit.setVisible(true);
        lbl_Balance.setVisible(true);

    }
    // Displays invalid if the pin is not correct
    else {
        lbl_Pin.setText("Invalid");
    }
```

I enter the correct pin, I am sure of this as I displayed the correct pin as well as the entered pin, and they are the same, but an invalid answer is provided

Comment: Obviously `pin2.equals(String.valueOf(getPin()))` is `false`, then. We can't really debug it for you with the information given. Debugging is not that hard anyway, give it a try.

Comment: using `String.valueOf` is a bit overkill here. try with `pin2.equals(getPin())`

Comment: Also, print the value of pin2 and getPin() for debugging. You will definitely found the issue there as the equal operator should work as expected.

Answer (score -1):

It might be an encoding issue. When you are reading the pin from the text file, please make sure that the encoding of the text matches with that of lblP=_Pin.

When you are reading the text file, you can mention the desired encoding while opening the file.

Answer (score -2):

I found the issue. When getting the Pin from the text file, '/r' was added on as part of the value. So I just made a substring with the actual value of the pin.

Comment: It wasn't added on. It was in the file. You read it incorrectly.